# UILabel inside tableview cell not updating its text

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, urlsession

I have a `UILabel` inside a `UITableViewCell`. I am downloading an audio to my device and using `UILabel` to show the download percent completed. This works fine as soon as downloading starts.

```
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, assetDownloadTask: AVAssetDownloadTask, didLoad timeRange: CMTimeRange, totalTimeRangesLoaded loadedTimeRanges: [NSValue], timeRangeExpectedToLoad: CMTimeRange) {

            var percentComplete = 0.0
            // Iterate through the loaded time ranges
            for value in loadedTimeRanges {
                // Unwrap the CMTimeRange from the NSValue
                let loadedTimeRange = value.timeRangeValue

                // Calculate the percentage of the total expected asset duration
                if timeRangeExpectedToLoad.duration.seconds > 0{
                    percentComplete += loadedTimeRange.duration.seconds / timeRangeExpectedToLoad.duration.seconds
                }
                print(percentComplete)
            }
            percentComplete *= 100
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateCell(Int(percentComplete))
            }
    }
}
@objc private func updateCell(_ percentComplete:Int) {
    self.myLabel.setNeedsDisplay() 
    self.myLabel.text = "(DownloadStatus) 
    (percentComplete)%
}
```

Now if I go to another view controller and come back to previous one again, (i.e. if I reload my view), downloading keeps going on but `UILabel` is not updating itself anymore. If I print the ?UILabel text it prints correct text but is not updating itself after reloading the view.

Edit: Note-> None of the outlets (i.e. button,labels etc) update inside "urlSession Delegate method" when the view is reloaded. I can see their value changes but not the UI.

Comment: can you post your implementation of updateCell method>

Comment: @objc private func updateCell(_ percentComplete:Int) {
        self.myLabel.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.myLabel.text = "\(DownloadStatus) \(percentComplete)%"
        
    }

Comment: add self.view.layoutifneeded() in updateCall after set text.

Comment: Don't implement asynchronous tasks in the **view**. Consider that a cell can be deallocated at any time when the user scrolls. Use a download manager in the **controller** or implement the asynchronous task in the **model**

Comment: @SagarBhut I tried it but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @vadian Tried it, not working.

Comment: You need a callback closure passed in `cellForRowAt` to the cell which is able to update the label continuously.

Comment: How/where do you assign `myLabel`?

Comment: @vadian I tried using closures too but still same issue persists.

Comment: @LGP previously I was assigning it inside my custom cell class. After Vadian's suggestion I moved my downloading code to controller. But still label is in custom cell class.